# Facebook Graph API - Unable to access public fan pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the graph API to retrieve information and I have stumbled upon an issue where the Graph API won't return any information. The page I am referring to http://facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry which one can publicly access and see, however when I go to the Graph API URL: http://graph.facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry it is denied. I understand that [Facebook explains](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/160155304123891) this issue by saying it is by design.

> We deliberately do not return a more specific exception for this case; the error message covers invalid IDs, non-existent objects, deleted objects, objects which are not visible to the caller due to demographic restrictions, objects not visible because the owner of the content has set privacy settings which exclude the caller, content not visible because the owner of the content has blocked the caller, because the **owner of the content has disabled platform apps from accessing any information about their account**, etc. *(emphasis added)*

So the reason is most likely that platform apps access has been disabled, however I see no setting for this anywhere, so I doubt this is the case.  Does anyone have any advice what is going wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The page I am referring to http://facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry which one can publicly access and see

Not really – when I click on that link, I get taken to the FB home page, although being logged in to Facebook. So I think it’s fair to assume that this page is *not* publicly accessible, resp. that there are access restrictions in place (based on country maybe, because age and alcohol restriction should not keep me from accessing it).

And in those cases, you can only get access with a user access token – because that’s the only way for Facebook to verify that the requester is allowed to see the content.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, apparently I thought I tested this for this page, but did not. I will look into the restrictions and update appropriately.

Comment: However, there should not be any country restrictions as when I am logged in as US user I can see it, and when I am visiting (and not logged in) from the US I can see it… But maybe there are.

Comment: There could be age restrictions, or country exclusions (i.e all countries except X)

Comment: But a country restriction should be enforced if he’s not logged in, right? (Or are they doing those IP-based or something?) And age can’t really be it, because age restrictions only go up to 21 I think, and then we should be able to see it I assume.